# SQL Serve 2016 Migration Advices

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have too many database on Sql Server 2016. Currently day my disk sizes begins not enough for my databases. And also cpu, memory not enough too. Sometimes jobs gets errors.

One of my one database is about 1.2TB and one of 500GB. I am planning to migrate databases to new server. I mean i am planning to migration. I have a some questions. I will suppose 3 disk. One is for datafiles, one is for logfiles and one is for tempdb.

What you thinking if a add extra one more disk and i will migrate my biggest database which is 1.2T to this extra disk. 
Can i get efficiency on performance ? I am thinking it will be better performance because data reads will be on different disks. Am i right ? What you suggest on this situation?

Comment: Do you use page compression and or columnstore indexes? This can decrease the DB size - And are your DBs set to simple logging? Either way, disk space is so cheap, so just make them big enough. And good idea to keep log,data and tempdb serperated.

Comment: No i am not using page compression and columnstore indexes. I will migrate my server but i havent got big experience on disk archtitecture. I confuse if i will add 2 disk for datafiles and if i will migrate  biggest 2 database to one disk and another databases to another disk. It can be more efficiency performance or not. Or how i should set  ?

Comment: try using this `EXEC sp_estimate_data_compression_savings 'Production', 'WorkOrderRouting', NULL, NULL, 'PAGE' ; ` Then you can estimate saving on using page compression

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some evidence that IO is your bottleneck? You should probably do some testing first. 
In case of perfect architecture you need to figure out your bottleneck first. If you have low memory then maybe (if you can't get more) you can move your tempdb on SSD drives so your spills to tempdb would be faster. 
Of course in most cases, if you need to improve performance (in most cases), it would be your database architecture.

Comment: thanks for advices i am planning tempdb on SSD drive, datafiles and logfiles will be different drive.